# editing the table in pandas PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need copy the value "a" lower and next I would like that the value of "b" will be also copied lower so many times until it encounters another value etc until the end of column 1

I tried to iterate through the rows and add conditions, unfortunately I wasn't get the result as I want.
My dataframe looks like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a |  |  |
|  | x1 | x2 |
| b |  |  |
|  | y1 | y2 |
|  | p1 | p2 |
| c |  |  |
|  | q1 | q2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Result as I want:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a |  |  |
| a | x1 | x2 |
| b |  |  |
| b | y1 | y2 |
| b | p1 | p2 |
| c |  |  |
| c | q1 | q2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: `df['col1'].ffill()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method=ffill`:

When used on a column, this replaces the `NaN` values in a given row with non-`NAN` values preceding the row.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, None, 2, None, None, 3, None, 4, 5, None, None]})

data["col1"] = data["col1"].fillna(method="ffill")

print(data)
```

Output:

```
    col1
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    5.0
9    5.0
10   5.0
```

**OR**

Use [`pandas.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) which works similar to above solution and looks more clean. Both the methods mentioned so far allows in place replacement of values.

Using ffill method: `df['col1'].ffill(inplace=True)`.